# Ayuden a crear mi arbol XML

Tags: c#, xml

Hola tengo un problema al poder crear un arbol XML, estoy empezando pero quisiera que me pinte esta linea al principio 
"" """", ya si se puede el cierre también pero solo lee el "UBLExtensions" más no el ext: y cuando lo pongo como variable string para que pinte todo, me sale error que no puede pintar los caracteres. Alguien que tenga un PDF o que alguien tenga la solución a esto ?

```
  //ENCABEZADO DEL XML
            string linea1 = "<ext:UBLExtensions>" +
                            "<ext:UBLExtension>" +
                            "<ext:ExtensionContent>" +
                            "<ds:Signature Id=\"signatureKG\">" +
                            "<ds:SignedInfo>" +
                            "<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n20010315#WithComments\"/>" +
                            "<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#dsa-sha1\"/>" +
                            "<ds:Reference URI=\"\">" +
                            "<ds:Transforms>" +
                            "<ds:Transform Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#envelopedsignature\"/>" +
                            "</ds:Transforms>" +
                            "<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1\"/>" +
                            "<ds:DigestValue>+pruib33lOapq6GSw58GgQLR8VGIGqANloj4EqB1cb4=</ds:DigestValue>" +
                            "</ds:Reference>" +
                            "</ds:SignedInfo>" +
                            "<ds:SignatureValue> AQUI VA LA SIGNATURA</ ds:SignatureValue > " +
                            "<ds:KeyInfo>" +
                            "<ds:X509Data>" +
                            "<ds:X509Certificate> FIRMA </ds:X509Certificate>" +
                            "</ds:X509Data>" +
                            "</ds:KeyInfo>" +
                            "</ds:Signature>" +
                            "</ext:ExtensionContent>" +
                            "</ext:UBLExtension>" + 
                            "</ext:UBLExtensions>";

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlElement raiz = doc.CreateElement("ext",":","UBLExtension");


            doc.Save("D:\\CodeDesign\\archivo.xml");
```

Quisiera que el resultado salga así.

```
  "<ext:UBLExtensions>" +
       "<ext:UBLExtension>" +
       "<ext:ExtensionContent>" +
           "<ds:Signature Id=\"signatureKG\">" +
               "<ds:SignedInfo>" +
                  "<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n20010315#WithComments\"/>" +
                        "<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#dsa-sha1\"/>" +
                        "<ds:Reference URI=\"\">" +
                        "<ds:Transforms>" +
                        "<ds:Transform Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#envelopedsignature\"/>" +
                        "</ds:Transforms>" +
                        "<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1\"/>" +
                        "<ds:DigestValue>+pruib33lOapq6GSw58GgQLR8VGIGqANloj4EqB1cb4=</ds:DigestValue>" +
                        "</ds:Reference>" +
                        "</ds:SignedInfo>" +
                        "<ds:SignatureValue> AQUI VA LA SIGNATURA</ ds:SignatureValue > " +
             "<ds:KeyInfo>" +
           "<ds:X509Data>" +
         "<ds:X509Certificate> FIRMA </ds:X509Certificate>" +
      "</ds:X509Data>" +
     "</ds:KeyInfo>" +
   "</ds:Signature>" +
 "</ext:ExtensionContent>"
```

Comment: a que te referis con que lo pinte. que lo pinte en donde?

Comment: Me refería a que me pinten los UBL <ext:UBLExtensions> así, porque cuando le doy un parametro y luego lo concateno no me llega a salir los : y también me sale error.

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement raiz = doc.CreateElement(ejemplo1 + "UBLExtensions");
doc.AppendChild(raiz);

XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null));
XElement nodoRaiz = new XElement("ext" + ":" + "UBLExtensions");

doc.Save("D:\\CodeDesign\\archivo.xml");

Comment: No entiendo nada. Podes agregar como te queda el xml y como queres que quede? pero en la pregunta, usa el boton [edit] y agrega toda la info que falta ahi.

Comment: Ya lo respondí abajo, es que necesitaba editarlo bien para q se entienda el resultado final.